# postgresql pg_import_system_collations does not import OS-added locales

Tags: postgresql

First post. Playing around with postgresql 11.9 on debian buster light, I wanted to add a new locale to postgreqls' list. Doing `select * from pg_collation;` in `psql` shows that the locale that I want is not in the list.

To add a new locale I first added a new locale to my debian by un-commenting the line `sv_SE.UTF-8 UTF-8` in `/etc/locale.gen`. Then I run `/usr/sbin/locale-gen` which was successful. After this both `locale -a` and `localectl list-locales` shows my newly added locale.

Now I would like to update the list of locales in postgresql that came from c-lib. This is done using `pg_import_system_collations` documented here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-admin.html

Running `psql` as user postgres and executing `select pg_import_system_collations('pg_catalog');` yields

```
 pg_import_system_collations
-----------------------------
                           0
(1 row)
```

So the new locale is not imported. I don't know why. Any ideas?

Edit: converted "update" with answer to separate answer

Comment: Hey, good question and solution. I got bitten by the same thing. Some suggestions though: 1. Maybe this question fits better over at https://dba.stackexchange.com/. 2. It is perfectly ok to add an answer to your own question. Your "update" section would fit better in one.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on dividing into two posts. I think I was not allowed to do that until I had some reputation. Done it now anyway :)

Im too lazy to add it to dba.stackexchange.com. If you feel that reposting it there would be a good thing, I wont stop you or complain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the above was done without restarting any daemon, service, the host or the like.

I have now made systemctl restart postgresql. Now the pg_import_system_collations works as expected. My conclusion here is that the documentation for pg_import_system_collations is a bit off. It obviously caches system locales on startup and they can be imported using pg_import_system_collations if that is desired.

It would be interesting to see if other postgresql-users see the same behaviour and if it varies with OS.